# how to extract the part before "/" character by oracle regexp_substr()

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I  want to extract the part before the 1st `/`, how can  I do that?

```
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('prAct1-03/cPMI-01/iPEPC9-01/t35s-08','(pr.*)/',1,1) as promoter 
   FROM dual;
```

did not work, and seems oracle did not support Lookahead and Lookbehind.
Thanks!

Comment: yeah, the `.`, metacharacter messes up your regular expression.  If you take a non-greedy approach such as this, `regexp_substr ('prAct1-03/cPMI-01/iPEPC9-01/t35s-08','(pr.*?)/',1,1,null,1)`, your pattern could work.

Answer (score 4):

I would just use the base string functions here:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '/') - 1) AS first_part
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

If you really wanted to use regex, then try:

```
SELECT REGXP_SUBSTR(col, '^[^/]+')
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Just `[^/]+` will do since both the start position and occurence will default to 1. Small technicallity =)

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('prAct1-03/cPMI-01/iPEPC9-01/t35s-08','(\S)(/.*)','\1') AS promoter
  FROM dual;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=95d17d21eca9223566e078a0e00bb0b3)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select substr('prAct1-03/cPMI-01/iPEPC9-01/t35s-08', 0, instr('prAct1-03/cPMI-01/iPEPC9-01/t35s-08', '/')-1) as promoter from dual;
```

[image]